# Ids get ordered alphabetically instead of numerically

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am pulling out data from MySQL ordered by id, which is 1,2,3 and there is no problem.

However when I use it with http://www.datatables.net/, the order becomes 1, 10, 11 ,12,..

I am not able find any parameter to sort this problem.

I am wondering if anyone knows how to fix this.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#tablesorter").dataTable( {
        "iDisplayLength": 40,
                "oLanguage": {
            "sLengthMenu": 'Display <select>'+
                '<option value="20">20</option>'+
                '<option value="40">40</option>'+
                '<option value="60">60</option>'+
                '<option value="80">80</option>'+
                '<option value="100">100</option>'+
                '<option value="-1">All</option>'+
                '</select> records'
        }
    } );
} )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to set the column type of that column to numeric, in order for the sort to work correctly. This is detailed at [the data tables website](http://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html_sort.html)